# Line painted with dojo is not displayed in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, line

I am using dojo 1.6 and find a strange behavior for painting line with surface in IE8. The line just disappears in some situations.
Here are the sample codes (ignore something) I used:

```javascript
var surface = dojox.gfx.createSurface("test", 500, 400);
var path = " M235 216 L240.5 216 M240.5 216 S244.5 216 244.6 212 M244.6 212 " +
           "L244.5 124 M244.5  124 S244.5 120 248.5 120.1 M248.5 120.1 L249 120";
var stroke = { color: "#63E4FF", width: 3};
surface.createPath(path).setStroke(stroke)
```

With such path and stroke, the line cannot display.
But if I made several changes for path or stroke variable, the line shows well. Pls see the following:

1. Modify width to 1 in storke variable
2. or modify the last "L249 120" to "L249.5 120" (change x) in path variable, but 249-249.4 doesn't work
3. or modify the last "L249 120" to "L249 120.5" (change y) in path variable, but 120.1 - 120.4 doesn't work

If you'd like to have a try, pls use the above path and stroke in `dojo-release-1.6.1-src\dojox\gfx\tests\test_setPath.html`. (download dojo sdk files).

I'm not sure this is a bug or I make something wrong.
Could anyone give me some advice on how to avoid such an issue?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Here's a fiddle with the code you've pasted above: http://jsfiddle.net/froden/ApLyf/7/ 
IE doesn't seem to render anything (there's no VML when you look at the DOM in Developer Tools). 
When changing the stroke to 1, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/froden/ApLyf/

Answer (score 0):

IE/VML doesn't support fractional coordinates --- they are usually rounded off. That explains your #2 and #3. This conversion to integers happens before any transformation is applied, so it cannot be fixed with magnification.

As to vanishing lines --- I saw this problem before, and I don't think it'll be fixed any time soon or ever --- VML is canned by MS long time ago. Try to tweak coordinates, e.g., multiply them by 1.5, 2, 10, or some other number, and use a transformation to scale it back to a proper size --- it helped me.